# Some but not all duplicates are removed from list (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Google Books api, to get some json data. My queries look like this for instance:

```
finalData[index]['volumeInfo']['title']
```

I am trying to get rid of some duplicates with the following code. This works to some extent, I have fewer duplicates, but it does not work 100%, as some are left. I am using the book ids provided by the json database to identify individual books.

```dart
convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      List newItems = convertDataToJson['items'];
      setState(
        () {
            finalData.addAll(newItems);

            var existing = Map<String, dynamic>();

            for (final item in finalData) {
              existing.putIfAbsent(item['id'], () => item);
            }
            finalData = existing.values.toList();
        },
      );
```

Is there a way of getting rid of all duplicates?

Comment: How are you saying duplicates are not removed? From Display? or are you printing value of `finalData`? Also the line `finalData.addAll(newItems);` is confusing, I guess its not needed.

Comment: From display yes, and also printing the list of ids. The line that you quote is here because I am adding items to a lazy loading list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `Map` for each request, so you are only removing the duplicates from each request instead from all the requests. You need to put this line outside the request method:

```
var existing = Map<String, dynamic>();
```